# Ruby - File.read() メソッドの説明をAPIドキュメントで調べたい

Tags: ruby

Rubyの仕組みを初歩から勉強中の者です。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/File.html

この中からreadメソッドを調べる場合はどうしたらいいですか？

特異メソッドというのはありますが、特異じゃないメソッドはどこにありますか？

Comment: メソッド名が先に分かっている場合は、[るりまサーチ](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/search/)が便利かもしれません。

Answer (score 5):

`read`は[`File`クラス](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/File.html)のものではありません。`read`は[`IO`クラス](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/IO.html)から継承して引き継がれているメソッドなので、[`File`クラス](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/File.html)ではなく[`IO`クラス](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/IO.html)のページを探してください。

**追記**: ご存知でしたらすみません。

[`IO`クラス](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/IO.html)のページを見ると、`read`の項目が二つあることに気づかれると思います。これらは名前は同じですが、別のメソッドです。

Rubyには`read`が二種類あります。[特異メソッドの`read`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/IO/s/read.html)と[インスタンスメソッドの`read`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/IO/i/read.html)です。二者を区別するため、前者を[`IO.read`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/IO/s/read.html)、後者を[`IO#read`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/IO/i/read.html)という風に書き分ける慣習があります。

[`IO.read`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/IO/s/read.html)の方は、ファイル名を渡すとその場で内容をまるごと読み込むものです。
`text = IO.read("hogehoge.txt")` のように使います。
ややこしいことに、`File`は`IO`を継承しているので、`text = File.read("hogehoge.txt")`と書いても問題なく動きます。(おそらくこれがmirukaさんのもともと調べたかったことだと思います)

[`IO#read`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/IO/i/read.html)の方は、すでに開いたファイルの内容を読み込むものです。
`open('hogehoge.txt') {|f| text = f.read }` のように使います。
<sub>(詳細なオプションは割愛します)</sub>

参考: [なぜ File.read() でなくて IO.read() なのか?](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/kwatch/20080924/1222268571)

Answer (score 4):

「継承」という概念の理解が必要になります。
質問が2つありますが、勉強中との事なので簡単に。。。

### Q1: File.read() のマニュアルはどこ？

探し方です。

1. http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/File.html を見て read が見つからない
2. 上記のページの先頭部分に以下の記述があります。

   - クラスの継承リスト: File < IO < Enumerable < File::Constants < Object < Kernel < BasicObject
3. 末端の File で見つからなかったので「上位」の「IO」をクリック
4. そこでも見つからなければ更に上位の Enumerable をクリック...(後は見つかるまで続けます)

### Q2: 特異じゃないメソッドはどこに？

特異じゃないメソッドは「インスタンスメソッド」と呼びます。
ご提示のページだと、atime や chmod などが該当しますね。

勉強、頑張ってください(^^)

Answer (score 3):

シェルから `ri` を使って調べられます。

```
ri File.read
```

出力:

```
= File.read

(from ruby core)
=== Implementation from IO
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  IO.read(name, [length [, offset]] )   -> string
  IO.read(name, [length [, offset]], open_args)   -> string

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Opens the file, optionally seeks to the given offset, then returns length
bytes (defaulting to the rest of the file).  read ensures the file is closed
before returning.

[...snip...]

(from ruby core)
=== Implementation from IO
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ios.read([length [, outbuf]])    -> string, outbuf, or nil

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Reads length bytes from the I/O stream.

[...snip...]
```

"Implementation from IO" と書かれているので、`IO` から継承されたメソッドであることが分かります。(前者がクラスメソッド、後者がインスタンスメソッドの説明です。)

Answer (score 2):

`File.read`は`IO`クラスのメソッドなので、`IO`クラスのAPIドキュメントを調べましょう。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/IO.html#S_READ

・・・が答えになるのですが、初心者の方はそもそも「どうやったら`IO`クラスのメソッドってわかるの？？」となると思います。

以下にRubyのメソッドの定義場所を調べる方法をいくつか紹介しておきます。

#### irb + methodを使う

irbから次のように打ち込むと、`IO`クラスのメソッドであることが予想できます。

```
> File.method(:read) 
=> #<Method: File(IO).read>
```

ちなみにgemのメソッドであれば、次のようにするとどこにコードがあるのかもわかります。（ただし、`File.read`のように、C言語実装の場合は`nil`になります。）

```
> User.method(:find).source_location 
=> ["/Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/querying.rb", 1]
```

参考: [Rubyでメソッドの定義場所を見つける方法](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/fc8a61b421d026a23ffe)

#### pry + pry-docを使う

pryとpry-docをインストールすると、`? File.read`や`$ File.read`でドキュメントやソースコードを確認できます。

```
$ gem install pry pry-doc
$ pry               
[1] pry(main)> ? File.read

From: io.c (C Method):
Owner: #<Class:IO>
Visibility: public
Signature: read(*arg1)
Number of lines: 29

Opens the file, optionally seeks to the given offset, then returns
length bytes (defaulting to the rest of the file).  read
ensures the file is closed before returning.

If the last argument is a hash, it specifies option for internal
open().  The key would be the following.  open_args: is exclusive
to others.

encoding::
  string or encoding

  specifies encoding of the read string.  [32mencoding[0m will be ignored
  if length is specified.

mode::
  string

  specifies mode argument for open().  It should start with "r"
  otherwise it will cause an error.

open_args:: array of strings

  specifies arguments for open() as an array.

Examples:

  IO.read("testfile")           #=> "This is line one\nThis is line two\nThis is line three\nAnd so on...\n"
  IO.read("testfile", 20)       #=> "This is line one\nThi"
  IO.read("testfile", 20, 10)   #=> "ne one\nThis is line "
[2] pry(main)> $ File.read

From: io.c (C Method):
Owner: #<Class:IO>
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 24

static VALUE
rb_io_s_read(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE io)
{
    VALUE opt, offset;
    struct foreach_arg arg;

    argc = rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "13:", NULL, NULL, &offset, NULL, &opt);
    open_key_args(argc, argv, opt, &arg);
    if (NIL_P(arg.io)) return Qnil;
    if (!NIL_P(offset)) {
    struct seek_arg sarg;
    int state = 0;
    sarg.io = arg.io;
    sarg.offset = offset;
    sarg.mode = SEEK_SET;
    rb_protect(seek_before_access, (VALUE)&sarg, &state);
    if (state) {
        rb_io_close(arg.io);
        rb_jump_tag(state);
    }
    if (arg.argc == 2) arg.argc = 1;
    }
    return rb_ensure(io_s_read, (VALUE)&arg, rb_io_close, arg.io);
}
```

参考: [Rubyでメソッドの定義場所を見つける方法](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/fc8a61b421d026a23ffe)

#### RubyMineを使う

さらに、お金はちょっとかかりますが、RubyMineというIDEを使うとショートカットキー一発でメソッドの定義場所を教えてくれます。

[RubyMineのコードジャンプ機能は本当にすごい！！困ったときはCommand+Bを押すべし！](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/bcb2bb5311a44113fdd9)

ちなみに僕はRubyMineを使っています。
Command+Bで定義場所を見つけてくれるので超絶便利です。

自分に合った方法でメソッドの定義場所やAPIドキュメントを探せるようになってください。

Answer (score 1):

`File.read`は親クラスの`IO`で定義されてるメソッドですので

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/IO/s/read.html

から参照できます。

ちなみに `File.ancestors`で親クラスの一覧を表示できます。

```
pry(main)> File.ancestors
=> [File, IO, File::Constants, Enumerable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: ancestores
継承リストをたどってみましたがありません
この場合はどう見るのでしょうか？

Comment: Junich Itoさんが回答されているように`File.method(:ancestors)`とすれば確認できます。

Comment: Class(Module)#ancestorsとなりますが親クラスの一覧の中にありません
どこから継承しているのでしょうか、何故一覧の中にないのでしょうか

Comment: そういえばありませんね。`Module`クラスの扱いがどうなってるのか自分にはわかりませんので、別の質問を建てた方がいいと思います。